# Reduce width of a column in my xltabular

Tags: columns, column-width, xltabular

what I have is this:

[image]

whose code is:

```
\begingroup
    \setcellgapes{2pt}
    \makegapedcells
    \def\arraystretch{1.2}
    %\newcommand\mcl[1]{\multicolumn{3}{l|}{#1}}
    \begin{xltabular}{\linewidth}{|l|>{\hsize=0.4\hsize}X|
            >{\hsize=1.8\hsize}X|
            >{\hsize=0.8\hsize}X|}
        
        \caption{Test Inserisce struttura}\label{Tab:test_inserisce_struttura_desktop}\\
        \endfirsthead
        \caption*{Tabella \ref{Tab:test_inserisce_struttura_desktop}: Test Inserisce struttura}\\
        \hline
        \endhead
        \hline
        \multicolumn{4}{r}{\emph{Continua alla pagina successiva}}
        \endfoot
        \endlastfoot
        
        \hline
        ID & \multicolumn{3}{>{\hsize=\dimexpr3\hsize+4\tabcolsep+2\arrayrulewidth}X|}{2} \\
        
        \hline
        Name & \multicolumn{3}{>{\hsize=\dimexpr3\hsize+4\tabcolsep+2\arrayrulewidth}X|}
        {Test Inserisce struttura} \\
        
        \hline
        Description & \multicolumn{3}{>{\hsize=\dimexpr3\hsize+4\tabcolsep+2\arrayrulewidth}X|}
        {Verifica la funzionalità Desktop \emph{Inserisce struttura}} \\
        
        \hline
        & Input & Risultato atteso &  Risultato ottenuto \\  
        \cline{2-4} & {Clicca il tasto \texttt{Inserisci} e riempie tutti i campi richiesti, premendo poi \texttt{Conferma}}  & {Inserimento effettuato e aggiornamento del Database} & {Superato} \\
        \cline{2-4} & {Clicca il tasto \texttt{Inserisci} e lascia qualche campo richiesto vuoto, premendo poi \texttt{Conferma}} & {Inserimento fallito e caricamento del popup \texttt{"Riempi tutti i campi"}} & {Superato} \\                                       
        
        \hline
        Notes & \multicolumn{3}{>{\hsize=\dimexpr3\hsize+4\tabcolsep+2\arrayrulewidth}X|}{-}  \\
        
        \hline
        
    \end{xltabular}
    \endgroup
```

- How can I increase `Input` column's width and reduce `Risultato ottenuto`'s one (and a bit of `Risultato atteso`'s one)? (`Risultato ottenuto`'s contente will always be `Superato`, so I needn't to have such space in that column).

Comment: Adapt the values of {\hsize=0.4\hsize} according to your needs but make sure, all numbers combined still add up to 3, since you have 3 columns. Alternatively you could use begin{xltabular}{\linewidth}{|l|X|X|l|}

Comment: already tried it but for some reason it is not correct

Comment: Will your multicolumns ever contain contents that need a linebreak in order to fit into the table? If that's not the case, a simple \multicolumn{3}{l|}{...} would be sufficient.

Comment: Which of the two suggestions from my first comment  did you already try and what exactly did not work?

Comment: Do you have a serious reason  to have an X  type last column?

Comment: Nope. No reason

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What about the following: Column 2 and 3 are equally wide with left aligned text in them, while column 4 is as wide as its widest enrtry:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{xltabular}
\usepackage{makecell}
\newcolumntype{L}{>{\raggedright\arraybackslash}X}
\begin{document}

\begingroup
    \setcellgapes{2pt}
    \makegapedcells
    \def\arraystretch{1.2}
    %\newcommand\mcl[1]{\multicolumn{3}{l|}{#1}}
    \begin{xltabular}{\linewidth}{|l|L|L|l|}
        
        \caption{Test Inserisce struttura}\label{Tab:test_inserisce_struttura_desktop}\\
        \endfirsthead
        \caption*{Tabella \ref{Tab:test_inserisce_struttura_desktop}: Test Inserisce struttura}\\
        \hline
        \endhead
        \hline
        \multicolumn{4}{r}{\emph{Continua alla pagina successiva}}
        \endfoot
        \endlastfoot
        
        \hline
        ID & \multicolumn{3}{l|}{2} \\
        
        \hline
        Name & \multicolumn{3}{l|}{Test Inserisce struttura} \\
        
        \hline
        Description & \multicolumn{3}{l|}{Verifica la funzionalità Desktop \emph{Inserisce struttura}} \\
        
        \hline
        & Input & Risultato atteso &  \makecell[cl]{Risultato\\ ottenuto} \\  
        \cline{2-4} 
        & {Clicca il tasto \texttt{Inserisci} e riempie tutti i campi richiesti, premendo poi \texttt{Conferma}}  
          & {Inserimento effettuato e aggiornamento del Database} 
            & {Superato} \\
        \cline{2-4} 
        & {Clicca il tasto \texttt{Inserisci} e lascia qualche campo richiesto vuoto, premendo poi \texttt{Conferma}} 
          & {Inserimento fallito e caricamento del popup \texttt{"Riempi tutti i campi"}} 
            & {Superato} \\                                       
        
        \hline
        Notes & \multicolumn{3}{l|}{-}  \\
        
        \hline
        
    \end{xltabular}
    \endgroup


\end{document}
```

Comment: This was perfect